# Django load a css that don't exists

Tags: css, django, static

Django it's loading a css file in my template even when i deleted completely the static folder. Some days ago i tried the collectstatic command, i think that could be the problem. Some clue about how to fix it?

Comment: Is the link to the css file still referenced in your template code? If not, it sounds like a caching problem.

Comment: Did you clear out the directory that the static files are collected *into*? You should be able to find that in `settings.py`

Comment: Yes brandon the problem was the chronium cache. I started a private navigation and the CSS it's not detected now. Thank you!